# How to fetch data from net faster and display in listView?

Tags: java, android

I have a news app. My app takes so much time to fetch data from server and display it on the listView.But i have seen that apps like flipboard,facebook and Game News which has more data to fetch than mine does it faster.I think my app loads the entire data and displays the entire list together.Is there a way to display the list such that it loads the items in listView one by one?I do the fetching using a AsyncTaskLoader in the background.Also how to display a large list of news like 100 in a list .

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.android.gametalks;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<GameNews>> {
    //IGN url
    final String ign_url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=ign&sortBy=top&apiKey=679f6fb918d34343b18590ca70f7fcde";
   final String google_url = " https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=679f6fb918d34343b18590ca70f7fcde";
    final String engadget_url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=engadget&sortBy=top&apiKey=679f6fb918d34343b18590ca70f7fcde";

    GameAdapter adapter ;
    private View progressBar;
  final   private int game_loader = 0;
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


urls.add(ign_url);
       urls.add(google_url);
       urls.add(engadget_url);
        //Getting listView
        ListView gameListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //progress bar finding
         progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

ArrayList<GameNews> gameList = new ArrayList<>();



        //Making a new arrayAdapter
         adapter = new GameAdapter(this,gameList);

        //Connecting ArrayAdapter to ListView
        gameListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(game_loader, null, this);

        //ListView item click listner
        gameListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                GameNews currentEarthquake = adapter.getItem(i);
                String url = currentEarthquake.getUrl();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<GameNews>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        return new GameLoader(this,urls);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<GameNews>> loader, List<GameNews> games) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       adapter.clear();

        if(games == null)
        {

            return;
        }



            adapter.addAll(games);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<GameNews>> loader) {
adapter.clear();
    }
}
```

GameLoader:

```
package com.example.android.gametalks;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by apple on 9/8/17.
 */

public class GameLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<GameNews>> {
    private ArrayList<String> Urls = new ArrayList<>();

    public GameLoader(Context context, ArrayList<String> Url) {
        super(context);
        Urls = Url;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading()
    {
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public List<GameNews> loadInBackground() {


        if(Urls == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        // Perform the HTTP request for earthquake data and process the response.

        List<GameNews> games = QueryUtils.FetchEarthquakeData(Urls);


        return games;
    }

}
```

QueryUtils(Here the network fetching takes place):

```
package com.example.android.gametalks;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;



/**
 * Helper methods related to requesting and receiving earthquake data from USGS.
 */
public final class QueryUtils {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = QueryUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtils} object.
     * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
     * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryUtils is not needed).
     */
    private QueryUtils() {
    }

    public static List<GameNews> FetchEarthquakeData(ArrayList<String> Url) {
        List<GameNews> games ;
        List<GameNews> Total = new ArrayList<>();
        URL url;

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,Url.get(0));

        for(int i = 0 ; i < Url.size(); i++) {
            url = createUrl(Url.get(i));



            try {
                //Make http request
                String jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
                games = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);
   Total.addAll(games);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException", "" + e);
            }
        }


   return Total;
    }

    private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with creating URL ", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readInputStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                return null;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // function must handle java.io.IOException here
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }

        return jsonResponse;
    }

    private static String readInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    private static ArrayList<GameNews> extractFeatureFromJson(String jsonResponse) {
        ArrayList<GameNews> games = new ArrayList<>();

        try {


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray articles = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");

            for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentGame = articles.getJSONObject(i);



                // Extract the value for the key called "mag"
                String title = currentGame.getString("title");

                // Extract the value for the key called "place"
                String description = currentGame.getString("description");


                // Extract the value for the key called "url"
                String url = currentGame.getString("url");


                //Extract value from key called urlToImage
                String urlToImage = "nn";
 urlToImage = currentGame.getString("urlToImage");

                URL urlOfImage = null;
                Bitmap bmp = null;

                try {
                    urlOfImage = new URL(urlToImage);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                     bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlOfImage.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                // Create a new {@link Earthquake} object with the magnitude, location, time,
                // and url from the JSON response.
                GameNews game = new GameNews(title, description,bmp,url);

                // Add the new {@link Earthquake} to the list of earthquakes.
                games.add(game);



            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + e);
        }

        return games;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Wow** *that's* a lot of code.

Comment: use retrofit lib for get data from server http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Use performance tools & http proxy to see where your time is being used by.